# Output/write SIMH DEC tape file to disk

Tags: vb.net

--->>> In VB .Net
I was interested in writing a simulated disk file in SIMH file format.  Essentially ASCII records are encapsulated with Tape (FILE) Control characters and binary record lengths. I know this is easily handled in C/C++ but I would like to implement this in VB.Net

First, Is there anyone can put an example on in writing table control characters to a data stream for output to a flat file.

Second, Example of writing to the SIMH format. I have have a PDF describing the the SIMH format so I'm reviewing this specification.

Thirdly, using the BitConverter to export a stream with binary tape markers encapsulating ASCII records. I believe i could use the BitConverter to create the binary file markers. However it seems I can use BinaryWriter, setting up a FileStream Handle.  If write the binary tape control characters with BinaryWriter how to implement one writer writing both Binary record lengths and the ASCII record? An example would be ideal.

SIMH is a derivative DEC tape format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim fs As FileSystem = Nothing
Dim infile As String = Path.Combine(<path_to_file>) 
fs = FileSystem(infile, FileMode.Create)

Using bw as BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(fs) 
    For i as integer = 0 to Headers.Count - 1 
        Dim lengthHeader As Integer = m_headers(i).Length
        If lengthHeader = MAX_HEADER_LENGTH then
            Dim dataArray() As byte = StringtoByteArray(m_headers(i))
            bw.Write(lengthHeader)
            bw.Write(dataArray)
            bw.Write(lengthHeader)
        End If
    Next
 
    For i As Integer = 0 To m_myRecs.Count - 1
        Dim thisRec As String = m_myRecs(i)
        Dim lengthRec As Integer = thisRec.Length
        Dim dataSentinal = (row * 6) + 8 + 2
        bw.Write(dataSentinal)
        Dim dataArray() As byte = StringtoByteArray(m_myRecs(i))
        bw.Write(dataArray)
        bw.Write(dataSentinal) 
    Next

    bw.Write(-1)
End Using
fs.Close()
```

Comment: Please, edit your post. Why did you make all your code as a quote?

Comment: No one else responded to my question so I figured the algorithm myself. and posted it.  As for the formatting I really don't have the patience for mucking with that.

Comment: You were in rush so formatting answer didn't bother you?

Comment: I suppose I should learn how to format code snippets but getting the content posted seemed to take precedence. Also there seems to be many who enjoy editing postings. I not using these forums for points or fame.